# How to detect that a point in the map has not street view

Tags: google-maps

I'm using static Street View url to get the image of a point in the map, but when a point has not street view enable you get a ugly image like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=-31.2703693,-64.3079765&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10

Any suggestion on how can mi app discover that the point has not a street view image, and avoid showing that ugly error image?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When your map uses the Maps-Javascript-API(it's currently unclear what your "map" is) you may try to use the method [`StreetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewService), e.g. for the given location it returns a status `ZERO_RESULTS`.

This method is intended for the interactive streetView, but I guess there will also not be a static image available when it doesn't return a result.